# Using quotes in MySQL where statement (column name)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Does anyone know of any way where you can use quotes in the column name in a where statement?

For example

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE "username" = 'Joe Bloggs'
```

Instead of

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'Joe Bloggs'
```

Here's why I want to do it.

I'm making a Laravel application, and i'm trying to create my own generic submit sql function through ajax, where a user can specify all the arguments they require.

For example,

**JS**

```
 var argument = "id";
 var argumentValue = 7;
 var value = "Smith";
 $.post('/genericUpdate', {'argument':argument, 'argumentValue':argumentValue, 'value':value});
```

**Global Controller (PHP)**

```
public function genericUpdate(Request $request){
  $input = $request->all();
  $argument = $input['argument'];
  $value = $input['value'];
  $argumentValue = $input['argumentValue'];
  $query = DB::update('UPDATE users SET surname = ? where ? = ?', [$value, $argument, $argumentValue]);
}
```

But unfortunately this runs the following statement

```
UPDATE users SET surname = "smith" WHERE "id" = "7";
```

If there is no way to do it in MySQL, does anyone know of a way to convert `"id"` to `id` in JS or PHP?

Comment: Column name cannot be parametrized. Of course you could build your own query with string manipulation (concatenation/interpolation) but it could lead to SQL Injection attacks. Choice is yours.

Comment: To add to the above comment, the reason for this is that allowing the column name to be determined by an external parameter, possibly coming from a website, would be a security flaw.  A malicious user could decide what information they receive in a select query.

Comment: In PHP, If you want to convert "id" to id you can try like this way ` 'UPDATE users SET surname = "smith" WHERE '.trim("id",'"').' = "7"';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query builder:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where($argument, $argumentValue)
    ->update(['surname' => $value]);
```

You should though use a whitelist to validate the column names. It could be something like this:

```
$whitelist = collect([
    'id',
    'otherColumn',
    // more columns
]);

$argument = $input['argument'];
if (!$whitelist->contains($argument)) {
    throw new Exception('Unknown argument');
}
```

Never trust the client. Even if it's your own JS code.

Comment: But I need to be able to pass the column name 'surname' in via a AJAX post request. So I need to be able to specify the column I am updating via a php variable

Comment: In your example `surname` is hardcoded. If you need it to be dynamic, you can use the same method as I used for `id`.

Comment: Brilliant, this works great thanks. Also, I completely agree the 'never trust a client' statement, but this is a personal application, and will only be accessible to me, my i.p and will have 1 user account, so I wanted to achieve it this way for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are made just so you can inject values in them. 
PDO don't have access to the query string combined with its parameters. The query and the parameters are sent separately to the database server